# node js POST request multipart/form-data, how to change name attribute

Tags: javascript, post, request, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a photo via a POST request with the request(https://github.com/request/request) or 
restler(https://github.com/danwrong/restler)

if I want to do like this form to upload photo to upload.php, how to set the input name attribute(value) (name="file")?

```
<form  action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" >  <!-- <<<this   -->
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="upfile">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/request/request#forms) you linked to:

> ```
> my_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/unicycle.jpg'),
> ```

`my_file` is the field name.

Comment: my_file is name attribute? if the <input type="file" name="file" > ,the set is  my_file: 'file' ?

Comment: No. If the field name is `file` then you would say `file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/unicycle.jpg'),`

Answer (score 0):

*This may help you*

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

*you can also see this link....*

[http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp][1]